# Using socket.io with scala and react

Tags: scala, reactjs, websocket, socket.io

I have used `socket.io` with `node/express` and `angular`. Now, currently I am working on a project where there's a massive need to either use polling or sockets. I think socket.io would be a much better option but I am really not sure if there's any wrapper for socket.io in `Scala`. 
Same goes for React, I haven't got any good information for any client for both on `Scala` and `React`. 
I would really appreciate if somebody points me in the right direction for this matter.

Comment: React is just a client side library, so it would work with sockets just like any other client side code or framework. as far as scala is concerned maybe this could help you https://github.com/jfarcand/WCS

Comment: Are you working on backend? If so, you might want to decide which web framework/ http library to use, most of them provide websocket support out of the box if that's what you need, for example, Akka-http and Playframework.

Comment: @Qingwei Yeah I've looked into those but I've found nothing pertinent to latest Scala versions. Can you maybe share some helpful resources?

Comment: @Umair, the latest stable scala version if 2.11.8, which both should support https://playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Home and http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.7/scala/http/ , note that play 2.5 is relatively new and introduced breaking change so many library support is not there yet

Comment: But that does mean that I won't be getting much abstraction as we normally get using a library like socket.io and would have to manually manage most of the stuff?